# disk has many bad sectors

Tags: drive

i've just installed ubuntu on my pc for the second time. when it started, i got a message about how bad my disk status is. after a short investigation, i found whats the problem exactly. it says:
reallocated sector count: warning normalized 100 worst 100 treshold 50 value 498 sectors
current spending sector count: warning normalized 100 worst 1 treshold 0 value 1 sector
the others are fine (good or N/A)
i dont know what does this data means, and i'll be honest - i dont really want to know...
but what i want to know if there is ANY chance i can fix this manually, or when the crash comes in, i can just throw out my hard drive.
if it counts, its a toshiba MK2018GAP 20 gb hard disk, and its really, really old. 
i installed ubuntu 9.11 on it.
thanks for helping me any way you can, if you can. have a good day!

Answer (score 2):

It means that your disk is on its way out, and you are in danger of losing your data suddenly.

**Back up all your data**, and replace your hard drive as soon as you can.

I had exactly the same error a month or so ago. I tried to manually fix my disk, and it seemed to work for about a week — and then the disk failed completely. Fortunately, I had had the sense to have a full backup of all my data.

Comment: i have no data on this computer, i just want to save it.  so, there is no way to fix it. okay, thanks for the response: guabaman

Comment: i meant to save my pc